# how to color points dependent on a numerical threshold using R lattice xyplot

Tags: r, lattice, scatter-plot

I would like to color the points in each panel based on the value of z.
The code that I currently have does not distinguish the z values from each panel.
I realize that I need a panel function and panel.superpose may be helpful, but I am lost.

```
x <- c(1:10, 1:10)
y <- c(10:1, 10:1)
z <- c(1:10, seq(1,20, by=2))
a = c(rep("one",10),rep("two",10))

xyplot(y ~ x |a,
   panel=function(x,y, ...) {
     panel.xyplot(x,y, pch=20, cex=0.3, col = ifelse(z < 5, "red", "black"))
   }
   )
```

The correct plot would only have the tope two points red in the "two" panel.

Answer (score 5):

This should be what you want:

```
DF <- data.frame(x, y, z, a)

xyplot(y ~ x | a, groups = z < 5, data = DF, col = c("black", "red"),
 pch=20, cex=0.3)
```

[image]

To clarify the ordering of the colors, `z < 5` creates a logical vector. Since `order(c(TRUE,FALSE))` puts `FALSE` before `TRUE`, this determines the ordering of the group colors. Therefore, all values of `z<5` take the second color and all other values of `z` take the first color.